# Is it possible to load two screens of pictures on top and on the bottom at the same time as on the screen with UITableview cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

*My code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ExploreTBLCellID";


    ExploreTBLCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[ExploreTBLCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        NSLog(@"new one");
    }

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    NSDictionary *distGetData;
    distGetData = [arrget_smart_category objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [imgMain sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[distGetData objectForKey:@"image"]]
               placeholderImage:imgPlaceholderExlore];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what it means two screens of pictures. Do you mean two rows or two columns?

Comment: @Yan currently it's load picture in table cell from top like default but i want lo picture in cell at both side at top row and  last  row also.
So is there any way to achieve this.